# SQLAlchemy - DeferredReflection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a fastapi app using SQLAlchemy.  This application connects to our legacy database and the architecture is a bit unusual.

For every client we have, we have a separate database.  There is a table called "prefill_data" (I didn't name these) which is basically a representation of their employee data.  So this table is completely dynamic from client to client.

So our application will receive the database name they are trying to connect to and build the connection string.

The issue we are facing is trying to actually query data from that table given the fact it's completely dynamic.  We have a somewhat working example by using DeferredReflection.  However, the issue we are seeing is this:

customer A connects to the database every thing works fine.

customer B connects to the database, then makes a request to this "prefill_data" table where we try to select something from, the query fails with `AttributeError: type object 'DynamicPrefillData' has no attribute 'zone'`.

I can actually reproduce this locally by connecting to one db, then logging out and logging in as another user who connects to a different database.  If I stop and start the server each time, everything works as expected.  So it seems to me the DeferredReflection caches the metadata so it doesn't reflect the table again.

This is problematic for us.  We need to reflect the table each time the db connection is changed.

I'm a ruby developer who got assigned to this project, so I have very minimal experience with SQLAlchemy.  I'm praying someone can help point me in a direction for a fix.

```
 database_url = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password"

    engine = create_engine(
        database_url, isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED", pool_recycle=300
    )

    Reflected.prepare(engine)

    return scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(
            autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False
        )
    )
```

```
class Reflected(DeferredReflection):
    __abstract__ = True

class DynamicPrefillData(Reflected, Base):
    __tablename__ = "prefill_data"
    __table_args__ = {"extend_existing": True}

    id = Column("sequence", Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the connection was closing causing unexpected behavior.